# Start a jquery script at time x with popcorn.js?

Tags: jquery, html, video, popcornjs

Is it possible to start a `.animate()` jquery function at time x with the popcorn.js libary?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  You are looking for the [`cue`](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/media-methods/#cue) method.

```
var pop = Popcorn.youtube( "#video", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oar9glUCL0" );

// At 5 seconds animate '#otherElement'
popcorn.cue(5, function() {
    $('#otherElement').animate();
});

pop.play();
```